# Lenovo thinkpad P15s driver problems

Tags: drivers, lenovo-laptop

I have a fresh Windows 10 installation and all the devices seem to need new drivers. I have downloaded all the drivers from the Lenovo support pages and installed them however none of them seem to be working. really strange situation any driver I install it doesn't seem to be working.

Please advise.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Uninstall all the non working drivers that you can, download and install Lenovo System Update. Run that and let System Update install the correct drivers.

Comment: That did help. At least i was able to make the internet work, however the graphichs driver still cannot be installed. The update doe not find it. The drivers on the support pages also do not work. I aslo tred drivers from Nvidia pages...also not working.

What can I do here?

Comment: Try uninstalling the video device (returns to basic VGA) .  Then restart and add the driver from Device Manager. Have it search for best driver.